# How ruby find module

Tags: ruby, metasploit

Say you have the code below.

```
require 'msf/core'

Class xxx

  ...

end
```

I have some questions about it .

I know if there is not a file in the `require` then should be a `module`.

1. Does `msf/core` means search a `core.rb` in the folder `msf` under a certain of path of `$:`?
2. `msf/core` seems like a path .Any definition syntax for it ?

Comment: Ruby has some predefined paths where are stored code files. When you require something, ruby will iterate through those locations looking for the file you asked it to load. In this case it will look for a folder 'msf' which contains a 'core' file. The syntax is the you use for everything else: folder/folder/.../file

Comment: Have you read [the manual](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-require)?

Comment: @YuHao Yeah. But still remain confused.. What does it mean `msf/core` in metasploit?

Comment: Then ask the specific question you have. The first and third question each are too broad.

Comment: @YuHao Aleady updated as you said. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know if there is not a file in the require then should be a module.

As I know `require` has nothing to do with module names. It always takes filenames.

> So how ruby find the module ?

It doesn't find. It loads a file and its content.

> msf/core seems like a path .Any definition syntax for it ?

Yes it is a path to a required file relative to `$LOAD_PATH` (`$:`). File extension may be omitted. In this case this is `msf/core.rb` file in your `LOAD_PATH`.

BTW this variable is `Array` which can be modified with custom paths:

```
$:.unshift('/usr/share/my_rb_files/')
```

> What is the difference between module and class?

In this case there is no difference.

---

I think [RubyDoc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Kernel.html#method-i-require) has enough information about how it works.

Comment: I search the `core.rb` in my root path . Why does't found a folder named `msf` which contains the `core.rb` file ?

Comment: Note that Ruby implementations are allowed to search for other file extensions as well, for example Rubinius will search for `.rba` (compiled Rubinius archive, similar to a Java `.jar`) in addition to `.rb`, JRuby will search for `.jar` and `.class`, YARV will search for `.so` (C extensions) etc.

Comment: I also search the key `core`, Didn't found the `msf` folder. thanks.